# merge objects in a given list based on object property

Tags: c#

I have a list of objects like List

```
    class Address{
        public int HouseNo
        public string Street
     }

    class Person
    {
       string Name;
       public Address location
    }

   List<Person> list1 = new List<Person>
                          {
                             new Person("a", Address x),
                             new Person("b", Address y),
                             new Person("c", Address z),
                             new Person("a", Address a )
                          };
```

I want to merge/combine objects in list1 based on same Person.Name

so the results contain

```
 Person("a", [Address x,Address y])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Dictionary< string, List< Address >> as intermediate container to create your merge, where the key is the name of the person and the value is the list of associated addresses.

First you make a loop in your original list, for each person, see whether the key (the name) is already contained in the Dictionary. If yes, then add the new address to the dictionary value, if not add person name as key and a new list containing the address.

You need only one loop on your original list.

At the end you can re-convert your Dictionary into any type of container you like.

I'm talking about the System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary< key, value >.

I have to learn how to format sample code here...:-)